# Would it be possible to get this theme work for wordpress multisite?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

I have been reading up on wordpress multisite and am a little confused with something.

When someone posts a new article on their blog what will it show up on my main site as? If they give it a category will it show up on the main site in this category?

This is the theme i would like to use and as you can see its in a sort of grid system so when someone posts something on their blog will it be placed here?

I have asked the theme author but his reply was a simple not been tested with it.

theme: http://themeforest.net/item/flyingnews-responsive-wordpress-magazine/4052664

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress multisite allows you to create several **distinct** blogs on one WP install. If you create a post on one of the blog, it won't be shown on the others. In the database, the blogs are stored in different tables (wp_... for blog 1, wp2_... for blog 2 etc.)